# Safe perl threads

Tags: multithreading, perl, memory-management

I'm trying to run a perl script with threads using the detach methode. The application
is supposed to run permanent, 24/7. I'm trying to use the [this example](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JDHEDDEN/threads-1.86/examples/pool.pl).

But when i run this example in a longer time period it turns out that there is a constant 
increase of memory. How can i avoid this? How can i use the `threads->detach` method without the increase of memory?

Comment: Perl threads have not very good reputation... perhaps it's time to find another solution to your application, could you explain it?

Comment: nothing special, a application which is runs a few paralell tasks but no double executions at the same time. It should be a boss/worker concept since i want to control the processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach may be the use of [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel%3a%3aForkManager) module (A simple parallel processing fork manager). I have used it and I get my work done (long running processes without memory leaks).

Comment: Switching from threads to processes isn't going to help a memory leak.

Comment: P::FM doesn't create long running processes. It only works if processes end periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code or what you are trying to detach?

you dont need to use pool.pl just to run a detached program.

The simplest you can do is

```
use threads;
use threads::shared; # if required,


###loop main prog

my $detach_thread = threads->create(

    sub {
         # DO YOUR STUFF here
          return;
        }

);

$detach_thread->detach();
```

Other alternative to consider is running in background (in unix: `yourcommand &`).

Comment: If you run the above code in a endless loop then you might notice a permanent increase of memory .... thats even the case with the example described here: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JDHEDDEN/threads-1.86/examples/pool.pl

Comment: wht version of perl are you using, I dont see it

Comment: There is some other variable that is leaking memory,or you might have accidentally added loop over thread->create() , it cannot leak memory untill you keep creating objects/variables in global scope and forget about it. Dont loop your program and just add long sleep after thread create and you will see which var is leaking.